# Logout with localStorage

Tags: jquery, ajax, local-storage, session-storage

I have a rest api with jwt authentication that I consume exlusively with jquery and ajax in the frontend. *I am not permit to use a server side language*.
During the login, I store the authentication token and the username in the *localStorage*. And during the logout, I clear the localStorage.

During the login:

```
localStorage.setItem('token', token);
localStorage.setItem('username', username);
```

When the user clicks on the logout button, I clear the localStorage and redirect him to the login page:

```
localStorage.clear();
window.location.replace('login.html');
```

But even if I clear the local storage, when I check the development tools tab of my browser I can still see all items that was stored in my localStorage. That means that a user can access a specific page of the application without really log in the application. This is a threat because he should access a page only after authentication.

When I choose *sessionStorage* over localStorage, the sessionStorage is really empty after logout. But a user can not be in the application and open the contact page (for example) in a  new tab. I would like the user still using the application (even if in a new tab) if he doesn't click on the logout button.

How can I efficiently achieve my requirements ?

Comment: The `clear()` method should get rid of any key/value that is stored inside the localStorage.

Are you sure that the `clear()` method is called ?

Comment: The `clear()` method and the redirection are in the same block of code. The redirect runs well, so I can affirm the clear method is called before.

Comment: I've already solved the issue. I will provide a more detailed solution very soon.

Comment: you can do invalidate jwt token from you backend when you are click in logout button